# Having Angstrom build and Poky build in one repository

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake, angstrom-linux

I have successfully made a test image (core-image-minimal) for Colibri-imx6 board using the poky distribution. The kernel does not completely load when the image is deployed on the board. So, I have decided to make a test image using the Angstrom distribution under Yocto.

The **specifications** are Ubuntu 18.04, Linux kernel-4.9, Bitbake 1.44, gcc 4.8.5, Python 2.7.15+, Yocto version Zeus, Poky version 3.0 and Target system is arm-poky-linux-gnueabi.
Below is a screenshot of the subfolders in the project folder:

[image: Build repository]

I wish to have more than one build folder, one for poky distribution and one for angstrom distribution.

The current error I am facing is the following after making the changes in local.conf in the new **build_angstrom** folder:
[image: Angstrom Error]

What layers/changes will I have to add to make this possible? Do I have to clone Angstrom distribution and keep it separately?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you include `meta-angstrom` in your `bblayers.conf`?

Comment: I included it just now. Any other layer, other than meta-angstrom that I have to include, or do I add meta-angstrom and do the change in bblayers.conf

Comment: check for the dependencies on the angstrom web-site

Comment: Okay I checked the dependencies. What image is the default bare minimum image, angstrom-lxde or core-minimal-image?